# Solving a differential equation with two parameters

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis

How can I code and solve the following differential equation in Mathematica:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(x^2  e^{2ax}\right) \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} + b x^2 y=0,$$

where $a$ and $b$ are constants?

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eqn = D[x^2*E^(2*a*x), x]*y'[x] + b*x^2*y[x] == 0

(* b x^2 y[x] + (2 E^(2 a x) x + 2 a E^(2 a x) x^2) y'[x] == 0 *)
```

Solving for `y` as a pure function (facilitates substitution into the original equation)

```
sol = DSolve[eqn, y, x][[1]]

(* {y -> Function[{x}, 
   E^((b (E^(-2 a x) + 2 E^2 ExpIntegralEi[-2 - 2 a x]))/(4 a^2)) C[1]]} *)
```

Verifying that the solution satisfies the equation,

```
eqn /. sol // Simplify

(* True *)
```

`y[x]` is then

```
y[x] /. sol

(* E^((b (E^(-2 a x) + 2 E^2 ExpIntegralEi[-2 - 2 a x]))/(4 a^2)) C[1] *)
```

where [`ExpIntegralEi`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExpIntegralEi.html) is the exponential integral function and `C[1]` is an arbitrary constant